# ASP.NET Membership/Role providers for Postgres?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, membership-provider

I am creating an MVC site and would like to use the built in Membership and Roles for .Net.
I'm using the the .Net Data Provider for Postgresql (Npgsql), but am having trouble defining the membership defaultProvider and Postgresql connection string to connect to my local database. 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not verified this, but will be using it in a project soon.  Hopefully I will have more info to follow, and it will "just work" :)

http://code.google.com/p/pgsqlprovider/

Hoping to use this software stack

Windows Server 2008
PostgreSQL
PostGIS
Castle ActiveRecord
NHibernate
NHibernate.Spatial
ASP.NET MVC 3 with Membership/Role providers

**[FOLLOW UP]**

I ran the NuGet command "Install-Package Nauck.PostgresSQLProvider" to install the PostgreSQL ASP.NET Membership Provider created by Daniel Nauck and Jason Sznol.

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Nauck.PostgresSQLProvider

Project Home
http://dev.nauck-it.de/projects/aspsqlprovider

You'll need to run this SQL to create the membership tables:
http://dev.nauck-it.de/projects/aspsqlprovider/repository/revisions/master/changes/src/NauckIT.PostgreSQLProvider/DatabaseSchema.sql

Finally the web.config file will need to be updated... I used this example for direction:
http://dev.nauck-it.de/projects/aspsqlprovider/repository/revisions/master/entry/src/Example/Web.config

So far authentication works, as does hashed passwords, all thats left to test is authorization.

Comment: Sounds very interesting, did you get all of it to work together?
Do you have some follow-up info?

Comment: All I have left is NHibernate.Spatial and Authorization to test. I'm hoping to utilize LINQ to run spatial queries.

Answer (score 3):

I was a little frustrated with the nauck version, so I wrote my own.  You can try it out [here](http://code.google.com/p/pgprovider/) it you'd like.  It has unit tests and a bit of documentation.

Comment: +1 but a downloadable binary would be great if you can put one up.

Comment: @Nuzzolilo, I added one for you. :)

Comment: I like your version over the Nauck version. (Thanks for including the salt and hash in the database user table.)  Your work is really appreciated.