# how to create asp.net membership tables in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-membership

I'm using MVC 2, Visual Studio 2008, ADO.NET Entity Framework, and previously my database was SQL Server 2008, now i changed it to PostgreSQL.

For implementing asp.net membership in sql server database, we will use

```
 aspnet_regsql
```

from visual studio command prompt to generate membership tables, view and stored procedures.

Now is there any tool or script to generate membership tables, views and stored procedures in PostgreSQL database.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759195/asp-net-membership-role-providers-for-postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Custom membership, i guess its the only option.